# Loading links within iframes inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm getting started with using `iframes` and am getting examples done from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). So far I have been able to load the webpage in an iframe. my sample code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is is there a way where I can click on the hyperlinks inside the iframe and that page again loads within the iframe itself without loading as a new page?

Comment: That should be the default behaviour. What happens instead? Can you show me some details?

Comment: http://www.littlewebhut.com/articles/html_iframe_example/

Comment: @dkellner - in the example above, if I click on any of the links of the site loaded inside the iframe, it loads as a new page

Comment: All of the links on that page have an attribute 'target' that is set to '_top'. In pages with embedded frames, this causes them to be opened in the root frame (i.e. in your case the page that owns the iframe).

Comment: Jack has the answer so I won't take his points away...